# Strongly Typed RedirectToAction (Futures) using async Controllers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-futures

having this code it gives me a warning : `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid id)
    {
        var calendarEvent = await service.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (calendarEvent == null) return RedirectToAction<CalendarController>(c => c.Index());
        var model = new CalendarEventPresentation(calendarEvent);
        ViewData.Model = model;
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<RedirectResult> Create(CalendarEventBindingModel binding)
    {
        var model = service.Create(binding);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return this.RedirectToAction<CalendarController>(c => c.Details(model.CalendarEventID));
    }
```

if I do add the `await` operator I get :

`Error  CS4034  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.`

if I add the `async` modifier like this :

```
return this.RedirectToAction<CalendarController>(async c => await c.Details(model.CalendarEventID));
```

the error is `Error CS1989  Async lambda expressions cannot be converted to expression trees`

So how can I use strongly typed RedirectToAction (I'm using MVC Futures) with async controllers?

Comment: I guess you need to write an extension which will accept `Func<Task<ViewResult>>` or whatever and then translate it into futures' version (non-async) of expression.

Comment: mm.. i can't make it to work :(

Comment: Since the expression itself is not executed, I don't think is problematic - other than the warnings emitted, which are really annoying. Disabling them with `#pragma` seems the wrong approach to fix it though. Let's hope someone smarter comes along and fixes this. The following link seems somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240702/can-i-generate-an-async-method-dynamically-using-system-linq-expressions

Answer (score 3):

I have figured this out!

I have a base controller and there I have an extension method for async redirects

```
protected ActionResult RedirectToAsyncAction<TController>(Expression<Func<TController, Task<ActionResult>>> action)
        where TController : Controller
    {
        Expression<Action<TController>> convertedFuncToAction = Expression.Lambda<Action<TController>>(action.Body, action.Parameters.First());
        return ControllerExtensions.RedirectToAction(this, convertedFuncToAction);
    }
```

this will prevent warnings. Then you can just call RedirectToAsyncAction from your Controller.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
       // Your code
        return RedirectToAsyncAction<MyController>(c => c.MyAsyncAction(params,..)); // no warnings here
    }
```